# function to purposefully have a high cpu load?

Tags: c, algorithm, operating-system, load

I'm making a program which controls other processes (as far as stopped and started states).
One of the criteria is that the load on the computer is under a certain value.

So i need a function or small program which will cause the load to be very high for testing purposes. Can you think of anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of this one :

```
for(;;);
```

Comment: Maybe setting a higher priority to the process executing this infinite loop can increase the CPU usage

Comment: I wonder if this code may be optimized out by the compiler :)

Comment: @Vlad: It probably gets rewritten as `while(1);` :-P

Comment: @Vinko: but it might be as well `while(1) sleep(MAXINT);` with the same observable effect (and less processor load). Well, my comment has more theoretical value.

Comment: @Vlad: I'd say CPU load is hardly a non observable effect!

Comment: @Vinko: for the optimizer, observable effect is only the value of variables (and the content output to streams etc.). And the processor load is a parameter to be minimized. So in the ideal case the optimizer might consider the optimization via `sleep`. :-)

Comment: I used this. I made a small change though, by forking twice before I did the for. which effectively allowed me to run 4 of these at once, and just killed them using killall. does what I want.

Comment: @Vlad: A C compiler cannot optimize this to include a call to `sleep` because `sleep` is not a standard C function. It could be a function defined by the application with different semantics, or even a variable.

Comment: Silly conversation here: if you don't want it optimized away, then don't tell the compiler to optimize it.

Comment: @R.. The compiler could invoke a call to __sleep where that has the same semantics as POSIX sleep.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, but that requires an arrangement between the compiler and the system libraries... And it would also be nonconformant on a POSIX system that implements the Priority Scheduling option, since it would change the semantics for whether a lower-priority process/thread could get scheduled.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to actually generate peak load on a CPU, you typically want a modest-size (so that the working set fits entirely in cache) trivially parallelizable task, that someone has hand-optimized to use the vector unit on a processor.  Common choices are things like FFTs, matrix multiplications, and basic operations on mathematical vectors.

These almost always generate much higher power and compute load than do more number-theoretic tasks like primality testing because they are essentially branch-free (other than loops), and are extremely homogeneous, so they can be designed to use the full compute bandwidth of a machine essentially all the time.

The exact function that should be used to generate a true maximum load varies quite a bit with the exact details of the processor micro-architecture (different machines have different load/store bandwidth in proportion to the number and width of multiply and add functional units), but numerical software libraries (and signal processing libraries) are great things to start with.  See if any that have been hand tuned for your platform are available.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to control how long will the CPU burst be, you can use something like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.scriptol.com/programming/sieve.php#c) (algorithm to find primes until a certain number) and supply a smallish integer (10000) for short bursts, and a big integer (100000000) for long bursts.

If you will take I/O into account for the load, you can write to a file per each test in the sieve.

Comment: Nice, but i found it didn't take up much load at a fast enough rate. I could be using it wrong. Cool name at any rate!